# Node JS Multiple statement queries

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, npm

I have started a project using Node.js and Express to connect a MySQL DB to my app, but in some cases, I need multiple SQL Statements to fetch data for the dropdown menus as they come from dimensional tables.

The query works and returns all the data I need but one thing in the documentation called my attention and I'm not sure I fully understand what is meant: (it allows for SQL injection attacks if values are not properly escaped)

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#multiple-statement-queries

What do they mean by "properly escaped"? Could someone please give me an example?

The query I'm running is very similar to this:

```
let SQL = 'SELECT * FROM dim_val1; SELECT * FROM dim_val2; SELECT * FROM dim_val3;'

connection.query(SQL, function (error, results) {
  if (error) throw error;
  // `results` is an array with one element for every statement in the query:
  console.log(results[0]); // [{1: 1}]
  console.log(results[1]); // [{2: 2}]
  console.log(results[2]); // [{2: 2}]
});
```

Is it risky? Is there any workaround to fetch data from multiple tables?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68713929/trying-to-show-a-demo-on-sql-injection

Comment: FYI, you are only subject to SQL injection if you are building an SQL query by inserting some user-provided content (where malicious syntax could be used).  If you are just declaring your own SQL as in your code above, there is no risk of SQL injection.

Comment: Here's an article on preventing SQL injection when you are using some user-provided content (like an email address): https://www.hacksplaining.com/prevention/sql-injection.